# How to remove object in array where key not available in array

Tags: php

this is my result $dataJson like this

```
$dataJson :

[
    {
        "42773": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 712584
    },
    {
        "42792": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 795000
    },
    {
        "42805": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 1536000
    },
    {
        "42887": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 711566
    },
    {
        "42773": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 712584
    },
    {
        "42792": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 795000
    }
]


$filter = [42792, 42805];
```

How to remove object whose key in date value is not available in $filter ?
for example here I want to delete keys 42792 and 42805 in the form of an array in $filter

I've already tried, but there is still data left using this way :

```
(array)$filter= [42792];
      for($i=0;$i<count($dataJson);$i++) {
        foreach($dataJson[$i] as $key => $value) {
          if(!in_array($key, $tmp_inv_id)) {
            unset($dataJson[$i]);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @NigelRen of course, i've changed my question with the thing i tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - How to modify deeply nested associative arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035858/php-how-to-modify-deeply-nested-associative-arrays)

Comment: No, I want to filter data with unset data where not in array $filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing your own loops, you can use `array_filter` with a custom callback function for stuff like this. Make sure you decode the JSON so that it creates associate arrays out of the objects, that makes accessing the first key easier.

```
$data = json_decode('[
    {
        "42773": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 712584
    },
    {
        "42792": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 795000
    },
    {
        "42805": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 1536000
    },
    {
        "42887": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 711566
    },
    {
        "42773": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 712584
    },
    {
        "42792": "2021-03-01",
        "jumlah_bayar": 795000
    }
]', 1);

$filter = [42792, 42805];

$data = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($filter) {
  return !in_array(array_key_first($item), $filter);
});
var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [42773]=>
    string(10) "2021-03-01"
    ["jumlah_bayar"]=>
    int(712584)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [42887]=>
    string(10) "2021-03-01"
    ["jumlah_bayar"]=>
    int(711566)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [42773]=>
    string(10) "2021-03-01"
    ["jumlah_bayar"]=>
    int(712584)
  }
}
```

Comment: I got error ErrorException: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file. when I try return json_decode($tmp_data,1);

Comment: Well then your $tmp_data obviously is not JSON, but a PHP array structure already. (But if the items are not associative arrays yet, but objects, then you will need to _encode_ it as JSON first, and then decode again with the second parameter set to true - otherwise, using `array_key_first` to dynamically get the name of the first key won’t work.)